# How do you pad a string with a given character or make it empty if length to pad is 0 in C#?

Tags: c#, padding

Is there a function that does almost exactly what String.PadLeft(int length) does except that if length is 0 make the string empty?
This is what I want to do:

```
string someText = "abc".PadLeft(8, '0');
Console.WriteLine(someText);

string otherText = "xyz".PadLeft(0, '0');
Console.WriteLine(otherText);

Console.WriteLine("Done!");
```

I want the output to be this:

```
00000abc

Done!
```

However, the actual output is this:

```
00000abc
xyz
Done!
```

Comment: And what do you expect to be the result of _"xyz".PadLeft(2, '0');_?

Comment: Write an extension method where, if 0, return empty, else return PadLeft

Comment: You would probably have to write an extension.

Comment: First parameter in padleft is column width, if you specify column width as 0 nothing will be padded as padding is only occurs when length of string is less than column width.Hence, you are getting "xyz" as output.if you want to return empty string you should check if column width is 0 then it should return empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such method. However, you can write your own [Extension Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) that does what you want.

This method behaves exactly like the classic `PadLeft`, except it returns an empty string if the provided length is 0.

You can easily change the condition from `padLength == 0` to `padLength < input.Length` if you wish to return an empty string if the padding is lower than the string's length.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string CustomPadLeft(this string input, int padLength, char padChar)
    {
        if (padLength == 0)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        return input.PadLeft(padLength, padChar);
    }
}
```

Here's the corresponding unit test to validate the behavior:

```
[TestMethod]
public void PadTest()
{
    Assert.AreEqual(string.Empty, "xyz".CustomPadLeft(0, '0'));
    Assert.AreEqual("xyz", "xyz".CustomPadLeft(2, '0'));
    Assert.AreEqual("00000abc", "abc".CustomPadLeft(8, '0'));
}
```

I also suggest you find a better name than my `CustomPadLeft`...